# Is it possible to version a asp.net site like you can do with dlls?

Tags: asp.net, version-control

Is it possible to version a asp.net site like doing so with AssemblyInfo.cs in Class Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments in the AssemblyInfo.cs in my ASP.net projects, you can:

```
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I tried it, and yes, it works.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

On the AssemblyFileVersion I get a warning while building.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In VS:

- right click web project,
- go to properties
- then application.
- Click assembly information button - there you have the version fields.